# RPM Missing dependency

Tags: dependencies, rpm

I am creating a RPM which has the following shared objects:

```
libexample.so --> libexample.so.1.0.1
libexample.so.1.0.1
```

When I am creating the RPM using `rpmbuild`, I see the rpm provides `libexample.so.1.0.1`.
But, in the require section I see `libexample.so`

In the `makefile` of the project I refer `libexample.so`

When I am trying to install the rpm it gives an error `"Missing dependency: libexample.so"` even though it is packaged as a link file pointing to `libexample.so.1.0.1`

So the problem is somehow RPM is not considering that I am packaging `libexample.so` (which is a link to `libexample.so.1.0.1`)

However, I installed the rpm using `--nodeps` option and everything is working fine.

So, my question is how should I modify to avoid getting the error of missing dependency.

To validate that the missing dependency is due to the link file, I changed  `libexample.so` from a link file to an actual shared object (`cp libexample.so.1.0.1 libexample.so`) and rpm does not giving the missing dependency error.

Can someone please help to tell me what I am missing and how to fix this missing dependency error in RPM. Thanks a lot in advance for your help and time.

Comment: The spec file has nothing fancy. All sections are empty except files. In %files section it points to the directory which has all files to be packaged. (e.g. %atrib ... /a/b/c  --  all files to be packaged are under /a/b/c; including the shared libraries.)

Comment: Either you are using the terms "provides" and "requires" wrong (which have a special meaning in the rpm context) or you are doing something really fishy. Anyways, post your specfile.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
rpm -q --requires _your_rpm_name_
```

And see if it's returning anything different from what you're expecting.  I suspect the automatic dependency scripts may be setting the dependencies to something other than what you're expecting.  You can disable to automatic dependencies by adding the tag below to your spec file, and then calling out your required packages manually:

```
AutoReqProv: no
Requires: _rpm_providing_libexample.so_
```

See http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html
and http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html

Comment: Thanks. The problem came into existence due to missing SONAMEs in some .so. RPM uses SONAMEs to build the dependency. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I think that the problem is that RPM does not know about sonames. If the RPM file has a dependency, it checks the RPM system.

See [my blog post](https://sparkyandsusi.wordpress.com/2016/04/29/psa-rpms-and-required-libs/).